# JQuery Multiple Scripts with document.ready() function. Just the first works in IE

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, scripting

I have the following problem with my new Website: http://clemenshamann.de:

If the page loads in firefox/chrome etc. everything works fine. Now if the page loads in IE 8 or 9 for example the page loads but only the first script declared in the header works (it fades the background image). The next two scripts just startk working if I press F12 to open the Developer Tools of the IE. Any of the scripts has there own document.ready() function.

Dows anyone have a suggestion why it caused that?

Here is some code: (You can watch the hole Code at the above given domain)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!--    Check for IE and set global variable-->
    <!--[if IE]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var is_ie = true;
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
       if (typeof is_ie == "undefined") {
           var is_ie = false
       }
    </script>

<!--    Enable bg image fade for all browsers but IE   -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/bg_fade_resize.js"></script>
<!--    Portfolio Slider Script-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/portfolio_slider.js"></script>
<!--    Seitenscrolling-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/scrolling.js"></script>
```

If you need more information please ask me.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you have some `console.log` commands in your javascript. IE only defines the `console` object when the developer tools are open (it is always defined in Firefox and Chrome ).

You will need to either remove the `console.log` lines or wrap them in a conditional:

```
if(console) console.log("message");
```